# Running two commands parallel to each other in R on windows

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have tried reading around on the net on using parallel computing in R.
My problem is that I want to utilize all my cores on my PC, and after reading different ressources I am not sure I need packages like multicore for my purposes, which unfortunately does not work on windows.

Can I simply split my very large data sets into several sub datasets, and run the same function on each, and have the same function run on different cores? They dont need to talk to each other, and I just need the output from each. Is that really impossible to do on windows?
Suppose I have a function called timeanalysis() and two datasets, 1 and 2. Cant I call the same function twice, and tell it to use a different core each time?

timeanalysis(1)

timeanalysis(2)

Comment: You should read [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) first, try some stuff, and then come back and ask a question if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: I have been looking at that document a few times, and a lot of the solutions in the document dont seem to work on windows. I was able to install the parallels package, but when I call the mcmapply function I am only able to enable one core anyway under windows, and then the purpose is sort of defeated.

Comment: As a quick solution you could invoke Rscript.exe your_script.R [func arguments] twice from 2 different cmd prompts. It will create 2 processes which will run on 2 different cores.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I was really hoping it could be done within a .R script file.

Comment: `parLapply` in the parallel package works on Windows.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like Rmip cannot be downloaded into R 3.0, on which parLapply is depedent. It seems like this would be much much easier on linux using the multicore package, where you can just change a line of code to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the [snowfall](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snowfall/index.html) package to be the easiest to use in windows for parallel tasks.